# R function for finding a specific repeat count for data.frame

Tags: r, function, filter

I want to create a function that will give a new dataframe only with rows in which for the selected column the value is counted exactly 2 times in the original data.frame

I try this:

```
duplicates <- function(df$x, as.bool = TRUE) {
  is.dup <- (duplicated(x) & rev(duplicated(rev(x))))
  if (as.bool) { is.dup } else { x[is.dup] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
oneDuplicate <- function(df, vec){

    ndf <- df[df[[vec]] %in% (which(table(df[[vec]]) == 2) |> names()),]

  return(ndf)

}

oneDuplicate(attitude, "advance")
```

```
    63         64         51       54     63       73      47
5      81         78         56       66     71       83      47
6      43         55         49       44     54       49      34
11     64         53         53       58     58       67      34
15     77         77         54       72     79       77      46
19     65         70         46       57     75       85      46
21     50         40         33       34     43       64      33
24     40         37         42       58     50       57      49
25     63         54         42       48     66       75      33
27     78         75         58       74     80       78      49
```

Comment: Thank you, but an error pops up
ERROR: unexpected input in:
"one Duplicate <- function (df, vec) {df [which (sapply (split (df [[vec]], df [[vec]]), \"
>}
ERROR: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: And as I understand later when calling the function as vec I have to give the name of the column?

Comment: Correct. Sorry, there has been a short sight of mine. give me one min, ill fix it

Comment: sorry @Daisy, I had to delete my comment while I attended to something. Didn't want to leave a wrong answe up. Try this one out

Comment: Sorry to ask again but on my data it shows:


oneDuplicate (df_30, "V17")
  [1] V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23
<0 lines> (or zero-length 'row.names')


Is it because the column V17

typeof (df_30 $ V17)
[1] "character" ?

if so, how should I change the  type of data in  column V17?

Comment: It means there aren't any duplicated. Since R has implicit conversion, there isn't a need for me to distinguish between numer and otherwise, so I'll update the function.

Answer (score 1):

In lack of data, I'm using the mtcars data. You can do:

```
duplicates <- function(data, var)
{
  library(tidyverse)
  data |> 
    add_count(!!sym(var)) |> 
    filter(n == 2) |> 
    select(-n)
}

duplicates(mtcars, "mpg")

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
6  19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
7  15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
8  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
9  10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
10 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
11 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
12 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
13 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
14 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

In this case, each of the "mpg" values appears exactly two times in the data.

---

If you want to do these checks for several vars, simply wrap this into an lapply command. The output will be a list of data frames.

```
lapply(as.list(c('mpg', 'gear')), function(x) duplicates(mtcars, x))
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately errors pop up

> duplicates <- function (data, var)
+ {
+ library (tidyverse)
+ date |>
ERROR: unexpected '>' in:
"library (tidyverse)
   date |> "
> add_count (!! sym (var)) |>
ERROR: unexpected '>' in "add_count (!! sym (var)) |>"
> filter (n == 2) |>
ERROR: unexpected '>' in "filter (n == 2) |>"
> select (-n)
Error in command 'select (-n)': Could not find 'select' function
>}
ERROR: unexpected '}' in "}

Comment: Any idea how to fix these errors?

Comment: Which R Version do you have installed?

Comment: type `R.Version()$version.string`. If it is lower than R 4.1, can you update your R to the latest version?

Comment: Tkanks after update it work.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but on my data it shows: duplicates(df_30, "V17") [1] V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 <0 lines> (or zero-length 'row.names') Is it because the column V17 typeof (df_30 $ V17) [1] "character" ? if so, how should I change the type of data in column V17?

Comment: Thanks again, and now really the last question how can I change the function, so that I can have more (columns) vars then one

Comment: See the answer @Jahi Zamy has provided in his answer. The zero-length response means there are no duplicates. I will provide an example with more than one column, but will take some time.

Comment: Also please clarify what you mean with having more than one column? Does that mean you want to check if you want to check duplicates across several columns (i.e. a duplicate means var A AND var B are identical) or do you just want to have several outputs, one for checking duplicates in var A, one output for duplictaes in var B, and so on?

Comment: I just want to have several outputs, one for checking duplicates in var A, one output for duplictaes in var B, and so on

Comment: See my updated answer for checking several vars.

Comment: @Daisy does the solution solve your problem? If so, please consider accepting is as an answer.